# How do I use regex_replace from TR1?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I've not been able to get regex_replace from TR1 working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tr1/regex>

int main()
{
std::string str = "Hello world";
std::tr1::regex rx("world");
std::string replacement = "planet";
std::string str2 = std::tr1::regex_replace(str, rx, replacement);

std::cout << str2 << "\n";
}
```

str2 is an empty string.

Comment: Try this: <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982382.aspx>. See <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982727.aspx> for useful background information too.

Comment: you'll need to be more specific. What is the output of the code above? Does it compile? etc...

Comment: What compiler (manufacturer, version etc) are you using?

Comment: gcc version 4.3.2 (Ubuntu 4.3.2-1ubuntu12)

Comment: Never mind, I used boost instead.